# Is it possible to lock bad bits in RAM on Linux?

Tags: linux, ram

Recently I bought 8 GB of RAM and it has bad bits. Is it possible to lock the bad bits to make Linux avoid them?

Comment: If you just bought it, why don't you return it and demand non-defective goods?

Answer (score 4):

There's a suggestion [here](http://gquigs.blogspot.ca/2009/01/bad-memory-howto.html). There's also a kernel patch called [badRAM](http://rick.vanrein.org/linux/badram/) but not, I think, for anything after 2.6.28.

The blog suggestion regarding memmap looks to be derived from a note included in the kernel source documentation, `src/Documentation/bad_memory.txt`; this note is still in the (currently most recent) 3.7.10 source as are references to the `memmap` boot time parameter (`src/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt`).  There are various possible reasons for incorporating such a feature into the kernel, and although this particular use-value may be unintentional, it seems like a sound idea IMHO and is worth a try (it's also very simple to do). I did not find any reports of it *not* working, at least, and the fact that the bad_memory.txt note has been left in the kernel source docs for 4+ years is a good sign.

Comment: Will you add some detail from that block post here? If so +1.

Comment: @Kazark: I won't repeat what is stated elsewhere, especially since I have not done this myself, but I did add a bit of context and explanation not in the blog post.  If czesuaf wants any *specific* clarifications, s/he's welcome to ask :)

Comment: It might just be that (as the recent removal of the documentation of the deprecation schedule shows) nobody went around to remove something that is moot since 8MiB was a large memory, costing serious money...